# TinyMCE autolink doesn't link if the link is the last text entered

Tags: tinymce

Go to https://fiddle.tinymce.com, then paste in a link. Notice that the link is not autolinked unless you hit a space/newline/etc character. How can I ensure that a link like this is autolinked on form submit?

Comment: If you use the _insert/edit link_ button, it pop ups a modal window where you can insert an URL and configure how to display it. This way, you "ensure" that when you paste the URL and click Ok, it is displayed as a link without hitting any keys. You could also use the **Link Plugin** from the documentation: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/link/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Not without coding your own version of the autolink plugin. The better result is to handle it on the server.

The provided plugin specifically looks for ')', space and Enter... It's not merely a paste issue either: just type in a URL without anything else and it will not autolink either.

The problem is, of course, the plugin has no reliable way to "know" you're finished typing/pasting a link.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution where I could trigger a call to the autolink plugin on form submit if text had been pasted at the end of the document.

Comment: Sure, but autolink doesn't have a 'trigger' other than keyup / keypress of certain keys, so there's nothing to call. Also, one must be careful with "paste" as there isn't really a paste event: you would need to look for literal Ctrl-V keydown, and you'll miss it if someone pastes from the menu. Check out source for the 'paste' plugin to see what needs to be done for that.

So, nothing simple, sorry.